# How many non-isomorphic graphs of 50 vertices and 150 edges

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an way to estimate (if not calculate) the number of possible non-isomorphic graphs of 50 vertices and 150 edges?

Comment: Yes (answer soon).

Comment: what makes that question a research question? I don't see what is special about the values 50 and 150 and the answers are also just numbers; does that help anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest guess one could make is $\frac{1}{50!} { {50 \choose 2} \choose 150}$. That is, we first count the number of labeled such graphs, then assume that most of them have trivial automorphism group so we can approximately divide out by $50!$ when removing the labels. You can estimate how big this is using Stirling's formula.

**Edit:** Actually, you can also just ask WolframAlpha to compute this estimate. You get $7.028... \times 10^{131}$, which is apparently within 1% of the true answer according to Brendan McKay.

Comment: Estimate $7\times 10^{131}$.  An average degree of 6 is not enough to ensure asymptotically that all automorphisms are trivial, but in this case it is true for over 99% of the graphs.  I have a Maple program that can get the exact number, but it ran out of memory.  The same program worked in version 9.5 on a computer with 1/4 the memory.  Bloat is everywhere.

Comment: so what is the answer spit by that computer?

Comment: If you want an even more accurate estimate you could try sampling a few million of these graphs randomly, using nauty to compute their symmetries, and applying the Polya enumeration formula.

Comment: That's how I got the 99%. Meanwhile, here is the exact answer:
708142715793532802254978664541059073304415243612497478993671318826722214752650148113161530130602853820921572607524821134602151577093

Comment: That is the exact answer for what question exactly?

Comment: @Brendan_McKay, I dare say that if that is an exact answer to the question in the title, it surely deserves to be expanded to an actual answer, with an  explanation :-)

Comment: @Mariano : The number 708...093 which I gave above is the exact number of isomorphism classes of graphs with 50 vertices and 150 edges.

Comment: 7.028, or 7.082? Gerhard "Expects Estimate To Be Higher" Paseman, 2015.12.08

Comment: @BrendanMcKay How much CPU time for that?

Comment: @Gerhard the estimate is lower, because here we count an isomorphism class weighted by $1/|G|$ instead of $1$, where $G$ is its automorphism group. Think about the case where we want to count all graphs with two vertices and one edge: the estimate suggests $1/2!$, the correct answer is $1$.

Comment: @Achim, indeed, I did a flip.  Gerhard "Not Enough Coffee This Morning" Paseman, 2015.12.08

Comment: Right, this estimate is the actual answer to a slightly different question, which is about the groupoid cardinality of the groupoid of graphs on $50$ vertices and $150$ edges.

Comment: @Wolfgang : Something like 30 minutes.  I didn't measure it.